# Publishing API's in WSO2 ESB using WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I can't publish API's in WSO2 ESB from WSO2 API Manager. My legacy architecture has two WSO2 ESB instances, first ESB is only a Gateway component, and second ESB works conventionally.

Now, I need to use an API Manager instances to publish API's in the ESB's intances.

But, I configure APIGateway section in /repository/conf/api-manager.xml to point to ESB instance, like this:

```
<APIGateway>
<Environments>
    <Environment type="production" api-console="true">
        <Name>Production and Sandbox</Name>
        <Description> Description of environment</Description>

        <!--ServerURL>https://${carbon.local.ip}:${mgt.transport.https.port}${carbon.context}/services/</ServerURL-->
        <ServerURL>https://localhost:8243/services/</ServerURL>

        <!--Username>${admin.username}</Username-->
        <Username>admin</Username>

        <!--Password>${admin.password}</Password-->
        <Password>admin</Password>

        <!--GatewayEndpoint>http://${carbon.local.ip}:${http.nio.port},https://${carbon.local.ip}:${https.nio.port}</GatewayEndpoint-->
        <GatewayEndpoint>http://localhost:8280,https://localhost:8243</GatewayEndpoint>
    </Environment>
</Environments>
<EnableGatewayKeyCache>true</EnableGatewayKeyCache>
<EnableGatewayResourceCache>true</EnableGatewayResourceCache>
<ClientDomainHeader>referer</ClientDomainHeader>
</APIGateway>
```

And, in  I tired to point to 8243 port as well, and I couldn't publish in ESB instance.

In logs, I can see following:

```
2016-05-05 08:33:29,551 [-] [http-nio-9443-exec-42]  INFO LogMediator To: https://localhost:9443/services/APIGatewayAdmin, From: 127.0.0.1, WSAction: urn:getApi, SOAPAction: urn:getApi, Direction: request, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body><ns2:getApi xmlns:ns2="http://service.gateway.apimgt.carbon.wso2.org"><ns2:apiProviderName>admin</ns2:apiProviderName><ns2:apiName>name</ns2:apiName><ns2:version>1.0</ns2:version></ns2:getApi></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

So, API Manager tries publish in ESB, and ESB recives request but I get only one error in logs a few lines below:

```
2016-05-05 08:33:55,865 [-] [http-nio-9443-exec-4] DEBUG AxisServlet
java.lang.NullPointerException 
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.getServletContext(GenericServlet.java:123)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.createMessageContext(AxisServlet.java:715)
[...]
2016-05-05 08:33:55,867 [-] [http-nio-9443-exec-4] DEBUG Options getAction (null) from org.apache.axis2.client.Options@353f3a03
```

Do I need to configure the ESB to do this?

Comment: Did you remove all handlers from template? Otherwise publishing APIs will have handlers and they required API Manager dependencies in ESB side

Comment: No, I didn't. Where can I remove handlers? In API Manager or ESB?

Comment: When API is publish to ESB you can see set of handlers engaged with a API. You may edit the velocity template to do that

Comment: I remove handlers in velocity template, default api template and prototype template, but I get the same error: "Failed to change the life cycle status : Invoking lifecycle action 'Publish' failed".

Comment: Wht's the error log?

Comment: ESB fragment error: http://pastebin.com/ZBDSnQ03
API Manager fragment error: http://pastebin.com/HUBngERX
I can see that ESB recive request from API Manager but due to any error it can't process the request.